# Should I leave the U.K. the day before my work visa expires?

Tags: visas, uk, work

I've a U.K. work visa that expires in several months.  Can I leave the country the exact day the visa is marked as "valid until"?  Or should I depart a day earlier?

Comment: I don't know the exact rules in the UK, I would assume leaving on the day itself would be OK but you should also consider the risk of delay, bad weather, etc. Planning to leave on the last day does not mean being able to do so.

Comment: Good point.  Ain't clear if they're forgiving about weather, missing your flight, etc.  I'm keep an eye on travel times to the nearest ferry too, thanks.  I'm asking about ideal scenario however.

Comment: @JeffBurdges On top of this check the immigration rules related to your visa.  There may be grace period allowed for you to move out of the country.

Comment: A question this serious should probably be addressed with immigration authorities rather than an arbitrary opinions on this site :)

Comment: I most often leave on the very last day of my visa validity and it's never a problem. I haven't done so in the UK though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are legally in the UK up to midnight of the expiry date of your visa.  If the date is 15 Feb 2014, for example, you have until midnight local time to leave.

Just adding...  If something happens and you can't depart, you can soften the effect by reporting to the Border Force (or in their absence, the police).  An Immigration Officer is empowered under Paragraph 31 and 31/A to extend, but he doesn't have to if he doesn't want to.  The police will slag you off, but at least you tried.

So it's midnight of the expiry date.

Adding:  For those interested in the 'grace period', the formal penalties start to kick in at 28 days.  Those are absolute and enforceable bans against entry.  But even for a time shorter than that, a subsequent *application* to renew or get a new work permit will be invariably refused on credibility grounds.