# Re-entering UK on ICT Tier 2 with four days left for visa to expire

Tags: visas, uk

I am in UK on a multiple entry short term ICT-Tier-2 visa which expires in mid-April 2017. My work assignment last day is 31st March 2017. After that I plan to go for a one week holiday to the Netherlands to meet my brother.

If my UK visa ends on 14th April and I return from the Netherlands on 8 or 9th April will I be barred from entering the UK?

The reason I want to return to UK is that my return travel from UK to India will be arranged by my employer.

Comment: @GayotFow I don't understand how these three linked Q&As answer the question here. He proposes to leave the UK after his job ends and then return briefly, before the printed expiration date, on the existing visa.

Comment: @MichaelHampton ok, I'll reopen it and add an answer

Answer (score 2):

Your T2 (ICT) expires on 14 April and your last entry date into the UK will be on the 8th or 9th of April. This is within the period of your visa's validity.

> If my UK visa ends on 14th April and I return from the Netherlands on
>   8 or 9th April will I be barred from entering the UK?

No. There is no reason (based on what you have written) for them to refuse entry.

An entry clearance ends on midnight of its expiry date. For you it means midnight on 14 April. As long as you are out of the UK by then, no problem. Note that your cooling-off period simultaneously begins at midnight on 14 April.

> The reason I want to return to UK is that my return travel from UK to
>   India will be arranged by my employer.

If the subject comes up, you can explain that to the IO. There is nothing particularly unusual about enjoying some free time near the expiry of a T2. The expiry on a T2 (ICT) is usually set at two weeks after the assignment finishes for reasons like that.

If you are travelling on an Indian passport, you will need a Schengen short-stay to enter the Netherlands.

You can take up further questions with your sponsor's Authorising Officer.

---

### Related and "near duplicates":

- [Can I visit UK a month before my visa expires?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51233/can-i-visit-uk-a-month-before-my-visa-expires)
- [Should I leave the U.K. the day before my work visa expires?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/23961/should-i-leave-the-u-k-the-day-before-my-work-visa-expires)
- [Can I overstay a UK visa? Can I apply for an extension?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/76058/can-i-overstay-a-uk-visa-can-i-apply-for-an-extension/76067#76067)